# Images not rendering with correct size in React

Tags: html, css, image, reactjs

I currently have a bunch of img tags within a React component and I set the width and height of those images on my css file to 270x220.  When I first open up the page the image is distorted but when I refresh or even change window size it fixes itself.

Every time I enter the site for the 1st time it is not the correct size.  Is it getting rendered before css?

```
render() {
  return(
    <div className="projects">
      <h1>Bringing ideas to life</h1>    
      <div className="single-project">
        <img className="img-logo" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dxfjyn0nq/image/upload/v1485547205/Splash_h4xwtc.png"></img>
        <div className="single-project-info">
          ...
        </div>
     </div>
   </div>
  )
}

.img-logo {
  width: 270px;
  height: 220px;
  border-radius: 20%;
}
```

Workaround: 
I added "this.forceUpdate()" in componentDidMount in the above component so it will render twice and this fixed the issue.  I still don't understand why it would mess up the first time since the css is applied (I can see that by opening dev tools).

Comment: Can you post the code so we can try to spot the problem?

Comment: Just posted the code.  When I go to chrome dev tools it shows that the .img-logo css is applied but when I uncheck it nothing happens then check the width again, it fix itself.  Also a refresh would fix itself as well.

Comment: every thing goes well [here](https://jsfiddle.net/8emquoj8/). Not any problem in your code posted.